# Something wrong with Groups.rotation?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have run the StageTest.java example in gdx-test and [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TiyjXirDDkw&feature=youtu.be) is the result when i click rotation.

It not only rotates the group and also moves it , is this a bug ?? 
And one more problem with origin in libgdx , what is origin in libgdx  ?? In my opinion it likes pivot ,right? It mean

- the origin is relative to the position
- the sprite is rotated and scaled around this origin
- the origin itself is not scaled or rotated in any way

But sometime I see the origin will move the texture such as :

`batch.draw(texture,x,y,originX,originY ..... );`

the final position of texture will be

```
(x+originX); (y+originY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't really reproduce your movement of the groups. But be aware that there are 5 groups rotating in addition to each image itself rotating. Comment out the following section:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (rotateSprites)
            stage.getGroups().get(i).rotation += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        else
            stage.getGroups().get(i).rotation = 0;
```

That will disable the group rotation. Maybe that gives some insight. From your video I saw that you have images that seem to be rotating around their top right corner, maybe that's deceiving, too. But in general, images and groups will rotate around their origin (like pivot).

In the above `draw(...)` method the texture will initially be placed at `(x, y)` with a given `(width, height)` and then scaled and rotated around `(originX, originY)`.

Answer (score 0):

All these are correct:

- the origin is relative to the position
- the sprite is rotated and scaled around this origin
- the origin itself is not scaled or rotated in any way

This is not:

> But sometime I see the origin will move the texture such as :
>
> batch.draw(texture,x,y,originX,originY ..... );
>
> the final position of texture will be
>
> (x+originX); (y+originY)

what [this draw](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) method which receives the origin does is using it for the scale and rotation (thats why this method receives a scale and a rotation too). If you want it to rotate with the origin at its center, this would do the trick:

```
batch.draw(region, x, y, width/2F, height/2F, width, height, 1, 1, rotation);
```